# Random dots on website?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a website, [NewGamingNation](http://NewGamingNation.x10.mx/), and I am generating most of the background via images, but none of my images have these tiny dots on them. I didn't add any code to it so that it makes these dots - not in my CSS or HTML file. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any dots. Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: I am using google Chrome and there are no dots.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iYYBDeq.png
They are very faint, but I'd still rather have them gone if possible.

Comment: still..where is the dots??

Comment: I'm seeing *very* faint dots dots near the bottom of the page - are those what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is problably the `bg01.jpg` background which is acting weird

i recoment using png-images because the quality of jpg-images gets reduced while saving them

Comment: I remade  that image as a PNG and sadly, I still did not get it fixed :/ thanks anyways.

-Edit-

Oh hey, it just took about 2 minutes but it updated :) Thanks a bunch.

Comment: DO NOT convert jpgs to PNGs unless you need transparency. The filesize, especially for large complex backgrounds will have a severely negative impact on your pageload. Use the 'export for web' functionality and export a jpg at 100% quality if you need it- the compression won't be noticeably different.

Comment: yea but this background wasnt complex

Comment: and even the highest quality settings for jpg is still compressed and will have impact on the image, if only slightly

Answer (score 0):

these dots is from the pic you're using as background.

Try add this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color: #A00210;
    background-image: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I already fixed it :) Thanks anyways, it was a problem with bg01.jpg - I Redid it as a .png and that fixed the problem.